# Joule Thompson Effect and Isenthalpic Processes

Tags: fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, compressible-flow

We are trying to compute the Joule Thompson (JT) coefficient for air going through a valve from P1 to P2 (where P2 is a much lower pressure).  Beginning this we were thinking that the water in the air was going to cause the flow to freeze when going through the valve but upon learning more we found this JT effect and coefficient.  Apparently this takes into effect the friction and isenthalpic (same enthalpy) characteristics of this flow to show how the temperature/energy changes through this.

My question being, does anyone know how to determine this coefficient for a process?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by the phrase "for a process"?

Comment: For gas flowing through a valve.

Comment: Do you want to experimentally determine it? Do you want to know how to derive the expression for the Joule Thompson coefficient?

Comment: I was looking for the derivation.

Comment: Check the Wikipedia entry for the Joule Thompson Coefficient for the derivation or your thermo textbook.